Подходит ли это определение слова "темп", если смотреть на контекст?
Допустим, есть словосочетание: темп жизни.
Подходит ли следующее значение слова "темп": "быстрота осуществления чего-либо"? Или здесь другой оттенок?

темп это от tempo - время; скорость ритма событий. Темп может быть как частым, быстрым, так и медленным - музыкальный термин.

Если бы вы сказали, например, про стройку, то да. А в случае жизни нет. И проблема тут не в "темпе". С ним как раз всё в порядке. А вот "осуществление жизни" невозможно. Осуществляются проекты, идеи, замыслы. Что-то перетекающее из ментального объекта в воплощённый в реальном мире. И при этом осуществление подразумевает процесс. А жизнь она сразу есть. Она не осуществляется, а скорее, наоборот, постепенно изнашивается. Так что к темпу жизни нет претензий. Но это будет темп проживания, темп событийности, но не осуществления. Осуществить вы можете жизненные цели, но не жизнь.

Темп жизни — это интенсивность развития/протекания жизни  в плане насыщенности/наполненности ее событиями.  Соответственно, подходит определение из словаря Ефремовой: Темп жизни  — это ИНТЕНСИВНОСТЬ развития/осуществления/проявления  процесса жизнедеятельности как отдельных людей, так и общества в целом.
Описание
**ИНТЕНСИВНЫЙ** [тэ], -ая, -ое; -вен, -вна, -вно. 
[франц. intensif (intensive)]. 1. НАПРЯЖЁННЫЙ, 
УСИЛЕННЫЙ.  И-ая деятельность. И-ое движение 
транспорта. // Дающий наибольшую 
производительность. И. метод. И-ая система 
сельского хозяйства. 2. Яркий, густой (о цвете). И- 
ые тона. Ткань интенсивного красного цвета. 
Интенсивно, нареч. И. работать. И. окрашенные 
цветы. ИНТЕНСИВНОСТЬ, -и; ж. И. труда. И. 
земледелия. И. цвета.

Из статьи "Современное восприятие времени и ускорение темпа жизни"
Ускорение темпа жизни
Понятие темпа жизни неразрывно связано, прежде всего, с социальным (а не физическим, научным) восприятием времени. Под темпом жизни понимается количество событий и ситуаций, происходящих за единицу времени в среде жизнедеятельности человека. В качестве событий в данном случае понимаются значимые для человека моменты всего происходящего, включающие факты и изменения в социальных процессах, существовании групп и отдельных людей, а также в жизни природы как среды существования человека.
Соответственно, ускорение темпа жизни — это увеличение с течением времени числа событий и ситуаций, происходящих за единицу времени.
Сочетаемость слова «темп»
Значение слова Темп по Ефремовой: Темп — 1. Степень быстроты исполнения чего-л. (музыкального произведения, произнесения слов в потоке речи, движений, из которых состоит какое-л. спортивное упражнение, и т.п.). 2. Скорость осуществления, протекания чего-л. (действия, процесса, явления) или интенсивность развития.
